# Different countries for release and beta in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

In play Store I'd like to allow my app for some countries (already done) but allow to every country in beta test as long as they are beta testers.

Comment: in beta testing your app tested by any one from any country if he/she added in google+ group.

Comment: It's what I thought but it doesn't work

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have a production app available in a few countries already but want to add a new country. I would like to invite some beta testers from the new country to test the language and such.

Comment: I'm facing similar issues. Beta/alpha testing complies to the supperted coubtries option and you can only invite people from those regions.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36148227/is-restricting-an-app-on-google-play-store-to-specific-countries-also-restricts/

Comment: Except this question was posted first @grebulon, so not a duplicate at the time :)